# Running Swing apps in IntelliJ Idea Community on a HiDPI screen

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, hidpi

I run Arch Linux with I3 on an XPS13 with 3200x1800 res screen.

I'm currently working on some Swing apps. When I run my app from the commandline with the java -Dsun.java2d.uiScale=2 myApp, the app is scaled (else it's just too small).

I also have the same line in my vmoptions file, but for some reason IntelliJ Idea does not upscale my Swing app when I run it.

How can I get IntelliJ idea to scale my Swing app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the scaling option in the **VM options** field of the Run/Debug configuration. `.vmoptions` file is used for IntelliJ IDEA itself, not for your apps.